# R timeDate isHoliday() wont recognize custom dates

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to use the isHoliday() function in R's timeDate package. I create a  timeDate object called ppa_holidays, which is a list of holidays:

```
years <- c(2012,2013,2014,2015)
ppa_holidays <- timeDate(c(USNewYearsDay(year=years), Easter(year=years), USMemorialDay(year=years), 
              USIndependenceDay(year=years), USLaborDay(year=years), USThanksgivingDay(year=years),
              USChristmasDay(year=years)))
```

Which gives:

```
> ppa_holidays
America/New_York
 [1] [2012-01-01] [2013-01-01] [2014-01-01] [2015-01-01] [2012-04-08] [2013-03-31] [2014-04-20]
 [8] [2015-04-05] [2012-05-28] [2013-05-27] [2014-05-26] [2015-05-25] [2012-07-04] [2013-07-04]
[15] [2014-07-04] [2015-07-04] [2012-09-03] [2013-09-02] [2014-09-01] [2015-09-07] [2012-11-22]
[22] [2013-11-28] [2014-11-27] [2015-11-26] [2012-12-25] [2013-12-25] [2014-12-25] [2015-12-25]
```

However, when I use isHoliday(), there are certain dates that return TRUE even though they are not in ppa_holidays, e.g.:

```
> isHoliday(timeDate("2012-12-08"), holidays=ppa_holidays)
2012-12-08 05:00:00 
               TRUE
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `isHoliday` function is also checking that the day is a weekday. By default it assumes Sat and Sun are "holidays" (or really non-business days) and 12/8/2012 was a Saturday. You can change the business days to include all the days of the week with the `wday=` parameter

```
isHoliday(timeDate("2012-12-08"), holidays=ppa_holidays, wday=0:6)
# 2012-12-08 
#      FALSE
```

Comment: This does not help. It doesn't matter what I change wday to, isHoliday() still returns TRUE for "2012-12-08" as well as many other dates that are not in ppa_holiday

Comment: I used your definitions of `years` and `ppa_holidays` and my code above and got `FALSE`. Are you sure you did the same? Tested with `timeDate_3012.100`. Seems odd your output above has "5:00". Are you sure that's the exact code you've written? What time zone are you in?

Comment: Using timeDate 3012.100 as well. And my apologies, I am indeed getting `FALSE`  for `isHoliday(timeDate("2012-12-08"), holidays=ppa_holidays, wday=1:8) ` However I am still getting `TRUE` for all Sundays.

Comment: for example:  `> isHoliday(timeDate("2012-07-01"), holidays=ppa_holidays, wday=1:8)
2012-07-01 
      TRUE `

Comment: @capt-calculator I goofed up on the range of weekdays. They go from 0:6, not 1:7. I've updated the post.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help. The R docs are rather lacking on this.